# Is it safe to hand over my mobileprovision and p12 file to my development partner?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have outsourced the development of an iOS app to a development company in another country.

Is it safe for me generate and handover the provisioning-file and p12-key ? Or can they somehow use them to publish apps in my name or something else without me knowing about it?

thanks
Thomas

Comment: Can you not add them as a team member? Then you can create a certificate for them only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be able to sign apps in your name.

In order to publish in your name they would also need your iTunes Connect password or an account there. Don't give them that and you are good.

You can also revoke the key and distribution profile after they are done for you so they can't further sign apps in your name.